# Breaking a cycle into 2 non-disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I have just started reading permutation groups and have gained a basic idea of the topic. I have a cycle of length $5$ given as  $(32541)$ and I want to break it into two non-disjoint cycles. I know there can be many such cycles, but is there any way to find non-disjoint cycles of equal length(say $3$)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

$$\begin{align}
(32541)&=\color{red}{(32)(25)}\color{blue}{(54)(41)}\\
&=\color{red}{(253)}\color{blue}{(154)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, I can check that by performing group multiplication on RHS I will get $(32541)$ but how to get RHS at first place? for example why not $(541)(321)$ or any other combination? Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586797/104041), @indmath.

Comment: So basically we have to break it into transformations(as we do while checking even and odd permutaions) and then combine two of those combinations at a time? @Shaun

Comment: It works in this case, yes, @indmath.

Comment: Yes, It will only work when we have even permutations and not in case of odd permutations. @Shaun

Comment: I believe so, @indmath.